# Recommendation for sequential least squares programming book

Tags: references, least-squares, weighted-regression

I would like to understand better how to solve least squares in a sequential/recursive way.

How to use weights in the least squares if the following problem:

```
y = A*a + B*b
```

where the estimation of `a` should be recursively updated, and `b` should be estimated each time separately.

Any recommendation for a book that can explain it well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lecture notes found at [Recursive Least Squares Estimation](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~tabus/course/ASP/LectureNew10.pdf) provide a nice explanation of the algorithm, plenty to use for programming your own solution.  You might also take a look at the recursive shrinkage or boosting regression methods described in the free Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman book [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/).

Comment: What if we only have new measurements and not new parameters / bigger model? I think it is called Sequential Least Squares.